# Android Room database LiveData Response with data from two different tables

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I have two tables,

```
ParentEntity ( id: String, name: String)
ChildEntity (id: String, name: String, parentId: String)
```

I need a liveData object that contains an object like this:

```
ParentEntity(id: String, name: String, children: List<ChildEntity>)
```

I understand I need some kind of join statement, but I am not sure how it should go, and what the return value should be.

it obviously cannot be

```
@Query("JOIN STATEMENT")
fun queryParentsWithChildren(): LiveData<List<ParentEntity>>
```

because ParentEntity does not contain a list of Children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use join statements, but common way for your case is Room's [one-to-many Relations](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#one-to-many)

You should add another class (without `@Entity`):

```
data class ParentWithChildren(
    @Embedded val parent: ParentEntity,
    @Relation(
          parentColumn = "id",
          entityColumn = "parentId"
    )
    val children: List<ChildEntity>
)
```

and your dao method would be without join:

```
@Transaction
@Query("select * from parent") // <- replace 'parent' with your actual table's name
fun queryParentsWithChildren(): LiveData<List<ParentWithChildren>>
```

Comment: hey need help over here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63266686/how-do-i-remove-row-from-recyclerview-using-room